# Echo success message after submitted form but before redirect and exit

Tags: php, sql, forms, mysqli, echo

Don't know how long i have worked on this, but nothing looks to be working. All i want to do is output a success message before it redirects and exits.

This is what i got to check for success/fail to the database

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO test3 (test1, betvalue, bookmaker, status, aktiv) VALUES ('$bettype', '$betvalue', '$bookmaker', '$status', '$aktiv')");

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) >0 ) {
      echo "Wow it works";                    <-- Not working
      header("Location: nybonus.php");
      exit;
    } else {
      echo ("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>" . $sql . "</div><div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>" . mysqli_error($conn) . "</div>");
    }
```

It does not output any echo if it has be successful, i have tried making it sleep with correct flushing to try to output an messsage, but it does not work at all. **Is there a better way to do it?** Also can someone explain why it wont echo before the header and exit?

Comment: there is no code to echo a success message is probably why

Comment: @RGriffiths Updated it.

Comment: Assuming your $sql is working, it is echoing the result and then loads nybonus.php so you don't see the echo. Comment out the header and see if it works.

Comment: @RGriffiths, Yeah i have done that to check and it works, when i dont have the header. But the problem is that i need the header and exit so on refresh it does not send again.

Comment: Can't you put the success message in nybonus.php?

Comment: @RGriffiths nybonus.php is the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you achieve what you want by setting a session variable and checking for the state of that variable on reload:

```
$message = '';
if(isset($_SESSION['success'])) {
    if($_SESSION['success'] == 'success') {
        $message = 'Success';
    }
}

$sql = ("INSERT INTO test3 (test1, betvalue, bookmaker, status, aktiv) VALUES ('$bettype', '$betvalue', '$bookmaker', '$status', '$aktiv')");
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['success'] = 'success';             
    header('Location: nybonus.php');
    exit;
}
else {
    $_SESSION['success'] = 'fail';
    ..... 
}

<script>
$("#message").fadeOut(2000, function() {
    $("#message").fadeIn(0, function() {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="<br>";

    });
});
</script>

<div id="message">
    <?php echo $message; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: That could be a nice way of doing it, but i have implemented the code, and i don't get a success or fail message at all when i try to trigger it.

Comment: Have you included session_start(); at the beginning of your php? Without this line session variables cannot be accessed.

Comment: I did, i can try again, might have done something wrong.

Comment: Kinda got it working now, but now i got a permanent "success" on the top of the page. Do i also need to destroy the session after to remove the message?

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. You want the success message to appear for a breif while and then go away? You could use setInterval to hide the element after a given time.

Comment: Yeah, i want it to go way because its on the same page, just want it for a few seconds

Comment: See edit - not fully tested but gives you an idea of how you can fadeout a message and replace it with a blank line.

Comment: That looks like what i was thinking, i will try more tonight. Thank you for the help. (I will accept the answer when i get it working tonight) :)

Comment: Implemented it in now, only problem i have is that the message is not removed after said time.

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: Yeah i'm using jquery.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hg6dwqmx/ but in my view this is becoming a little clunky. Would you not find it easier to direct to a seperate success page where you can do all that you want and then either have a button to redirect back or make it do it automattically after a set period.

Comment: Yeah, i think i will do that, makes it much easier as its still not how i want it. Anyway thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you use the "header" it has to be first.
You can't print anything else to the screen before the header. 
It's the same as when you're setting cookies.

So in your case you can't do the redirect with "header".
You could use a meta refresh.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.somewebsite.com">
```

The "content" is number of seconds to wait before doing refresh.

Comment: That works but, before the meta tag i put an echo to display an success message, but it puts the message on a blank page, then the meta redirects back to the orginal page which is right. How do i get it to echo on the same page not on a blank one?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to explain what you're trying to accomplish more precisely... like step 1 do this step 2 do this and so on.
Previously I understood you had asked how to do a redirect after echoing a message.

So now explain more detail in steps what you're wanting to do and maybe I can help.

If you mean the user is one "page1" and they submit a form and then on the resulting page you want to display the message? Then redirect...

You would just need to make the form action be the same url path as the page they are currently on.

Do you follow me?